# TNS error on Tomcat

Tags: jsp, oracle10g, tomcat7

I am working on a social networking website project. To shorten my code from the website pages that will be displayed to the user, I have have made a different class which i have included in my various pages and i use the different functions defined in the class.

For example: I want to display the details of the user, this is the code for that:

```
            User objUser=new User();
            ResultSet rs=objUser.getAllDetails(userName);
            rs.next();
            data="<div id=text>"+
            "<table>"+
            "<tr><td colspan=2><h1>User Details<hr></h1></td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>First Name: </td><td>"+rs.getString("firstname")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Last Name: </td><td>"+rs.getString("lastname")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>User Name: </td><td>"+rs.getString("username")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Mail Id: </td><td>"+rs.getString("mailid")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Contact: </td><td>"+rs.getString("contact")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Course: </td><td>"+rs.getString("course")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Branch: </td><td>"+rs.getString("branch")+"</td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td>Year: </td><td>"+rs.getString("year")+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>"+
            "</div>";
```

This is my code to retrieve the details. My class name is User, I create an object of it and use a function defined in it to return me the result which i process and store as a string and then later print.

This is the code of my functon getAllDetails()

```
    public ResultSet getAllDetails(String userName)
    {
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName(application.getInitParameter("driver"));
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(application.getInitParameter("url"),application.getInitParameter("username"),application.getInitParameter("password"));
            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from userfinal where username='"+userName+"'");
            return rs;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return rs;
        }   
    }
```

Now, the problem is if I run my webapp for quite a while i get a TNS error, which i believe occurs because there are no open connection because all the connections are occupied. The problem is that I am not closing the connection which i establish in my getDetails() function, but if I try closing the connection before returning the the ResultSet then it shows an error that connection has been closed. If i close it after returning the object, i don't think that makes any sense, but I also tried it and the errors says that the code after the return statement is never executed. And if I try closing the connection in a Finally block, then it doesn't recognize the variable st and con.

One solution i believe would be to increase the number of connections, but I don't think that is good, because if ever I make this app live and there are many users to it, I cannot go on increasing the connections to an infinite number of connections.

Please help. Thanks in advance for your help. I hope I could make myself clear in what I intended to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. First of all getConnection() is in a wrong place, too deep. Use getConnection() on the beginning of a user session, on the same level of code where you would be able to finally assert that all the results have been read from database and you can safely close() the connection.

Or better, google "connection pooling" to see how you can design this even more efficiently.